# Is there a way in RxSwift to observe changes inside an array w/o setting a new value?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

[Sample code]

```
let persons = Variable<[[String: Any]]> = Variable([
    [
        [
            "name": "John Smith"
        ]
    ]
])

persons.first!["name"] = "Joe Smith"
```

Can we observe changes to **persons**?

Or we need to set a value again? Just to emit, like this.

```
persons.value = persons.value
```

By the way I'm new in RxSwift.

Comment: Welcome to RxSwift! Be sure to check out http://reactivex.io for lots of good general info about Rx.

Comment: `Variable` is removed in RxSwift4, could you update your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the code setup, you have to assign to `value` to change anything. You cannot just update one member.

If you had a Variable of Variables, then you could update individual items in the array.

```
let persons: Variable<[Variable<[String: Any]>]> = Variable([Variable<[String: Any]>(["name": "John Smith"])])
```

To reconstitute the array of dictionaries you would have to map.

```
persons.value.map { $0.value }
```

There's probably a better way of setting up your model though.